# What secondary technologies are implied by a reactionless sublight drive?

Tags: space-travel

In my far future setting, I'd like to have starships that can reach near light speeds in narratively convenient amounts of time (days or weeks) and not be giant tanks of reaction mass.  Such a drive system would manipulate spacetime/gravity in a way currently impossible by known physics.

By allowing this, must I also allow secondary technologies such as repulsive shields, tractor beams, anti-gravity levitation, artificial gravity floors, etc.?

I realize that planet-killing kinetic missiles are an unavoidable consequence, as has been discussed thoroughly here.

(I'm not talking about an Alcubierre-style FTL drive.  FTL communication and travel are strictly forbidden in this setting.)

Comment: If it's a way currently impossible by known physics but you don't tell us how, how do you expect us to infer the derivative technologies?

Comment: Do your ships still have to carry the energy supply required to accelerate and decelerate?

Comment: If you can't tell us *how* the manipulation of spacetime/gravity occurs, then it's kind of hard to know what secondary technologies exist. Not to mention that even if you did, this question would probably be classified as 'too broad' anyway. Generally, if you're going to go with a soft sci-fi approach like this, it's actually a better idea to come up with the restrictions first and *then* apply the sci-fi technobabble. That, or take an established set of rules and choose to use that instead.

Comment: Maybe the how is the question I should be asking then?

Comment: Alexander: Yes, I'd like to avoid any free energy or perpetual motion machines.

Comment: Clarification: With the nearest star something like 4 ly away, I'd hardly call subluminal velocities "narratively convenient". You could air a whole soap opera of life on board the starship and still not even reach the destination! If everything happens within the confines of the Solar System (about 1.5 ly across), then okay. But that's not really a starship!

Comment: sure it is... it is a "star ship" not a "stars ship".  Also, most places in the solar system you might want to visit will be within Saturn's orbit.  So the longest trip you would likely make is from one of Saturn to Jupiter's moons when they are on opposite sides of the sun which is only 14.7au  worst case scenario.  Even at 0.1C, you could make that trip in less than a day.

Comment: Unless this story is about interstellar travel, even maxing out at .01C would still be narratively convient.

Comment: oh wait, I re-read the OP and he says he want to reach near light speeds in days or weeks, not that he has to reach a destination in that time.

Comment: Nosajimiki: yes, I'd like narratively convenient travel times for the protagonists (due to time dilation).  The passing of decades or centuries at "home" would be part of the story.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question! Will provide the most troublesome in a few areas.

Protection from acceleration. If you aim to hit high speeds, your human crew can only take so much before turning into tomato paste.

Protection against collision vs micrometeorites. At those speeds, even colliding against a grain of sand will damage your structure unless you can push it aside, absorb the impact or desintegrate it.

Communications at those speeds may be fuzzy unless you work around that issue. We are used to instant communication. Much depends on it, relaying news and asking for clarifications.

Law and law enforcement. If you are in the sea, you are subject to pirates attacks. Here the police may take weeks to reach your position, hence, crime.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for your response!  How do you think communication would be affected at relativistic speeds?  Would it even be possible?

Comment: Remember that time behaves different at relativistic speeds. Your communications software will need to decompress the time or speed it up to receive/send info.

Comment: It certainly sounds like the data rate would be greatly reduced.

Comment: Depends on if you are moving towards or away from your recipient.  Moving appart you would redshift causing a slower data feed.  Moving together you would blueshift causing a higher data feed.

Answer (score 1):

An Alcubierre drive IS how you move by manipulating spacetime/gravity.  It is important to note the theory of relativity says that you CAN go faster than 1C if you can make arbitrary manipulations to spacetime/gravity. You can not add this technology without making exceeding 1C theoretically possible, but this is not the same as it being possible in practice. For an Alcubierre Drive to allow FTL, you have to make a gradient steep enough to multiply your speed by a factor that exceeds 1C.  One factor often ignored in scifi is that that an Alcubierre drive would put your ship under shearing forces that would rip your ship apart if they get too strong.

[image]

This puts a soft cap on how fast you can really make an Alcubierre drive since it means that at some point, you're going to make a black hole in front of you so strong that the nose of your ship will crush, and a white hole behind you so strong that your tail end is ripped apart.  If you simply say that material technology only allows a maximum spacetime slope of ~100:1 before your ship is torn apart, and  traditional thrusters can't exceed 3000km/sec. then FTL is still impossible for all practical purposes.

As Adrian Colomitchi points out, there is the added risk of the gamma ray burst when you come out of warp.  While this is not a big risk to nearby planets when you come out of warp when traveling shorter ranges, it is another huge engineering hurdle for your ship when it comes to space travel.  If you stay under light speed, your positive mass equivalent field in front of your ship will bleed off radiation as you travel instead of building it up indefinitely.  This radiation will intensify as you get closer to 1C, but once you hit 1C, the radiation falls off quickly and builds up like a tiny nuclear bomb in front of your ship that would create a devastating explosion as you drop below 1C again.

To maintain the safety of space travel you will need a radiation shield to deflect/absorb the radiation, but you can not go faster than the shield can safely protect from.  This shield (weather it be magnetic or physical in nature) will also have physical limitations on how much it can protect you from.

The most famous example of FTL Alcubierre drives is the Star Trek warp drive, but Star Trek also has technologies such as inertia dampeners, bussard collectors, navigational deflectors, and structural integrity field generators which are all necessary for hand waving away the engineering limitations of an FTL Alcubierre drive. If you simply don't add these exoctic technolies to your fiction, then you won't have a functional FTL drive.

These limits also prevent FTL communications since you need a physical entity to generate the warp field, and that entity would by its very nature be subject to all the same physical limits as a ship.

### Do you need to include the other listed techs in your setting?

Technically you don't need any other technologies if Alcubierre drives are a new thing.  Other stuff may be doable, but won't be done for many more years because they all need more RnD to implement.  But if we assume this is a mature technology:

**Repulsive shields (Limited):**  If the technology behind an Alcubierre drive requires you to build your negative/positive mass somewhere in the structure of your ship, then the maximum repulsive power of your shield would correspond to a constant pressure against the structure of your ship.  This would mean that creating enough negative mass to stop a bullet would apply the same force to your ship as you are applying to the bullet.  This might have some practical purposes akin to "impact distribution" or "parrying" attacks, but they will not be some crazy over-powered invulnerability device.

**Tractor beams (No):** If you need your negative/positive mass somewhere in the structure of your ship, then tractor beams would not be particularly feasible.  You'd crush your own ship into oblivion long before you give a far away object any noticeable nudge.

**Anti-gravity levitation (Sort of):**  You could point a weak Alcubierre drive upward from the pull of gravity to create an opposite and equal force.  This will not nullify the existing gravy, just overcome it like how helicopters overcome gravity with giant propeller.

**Artificial gravity floors (Limited):** There may be a minimum size you can practically make an Alcubierre drive such that they would not fit into any reasonable flooring.  Also, if this were doable, you'd cause your ship to "fall" away from the gravity; so, you'd be a bit limited on where you could install it.

**Planet-killing kinetic missiles (No)**: One theory of how Alcubierre Drive equations might balance is by offsetting the effective mass of the moving body; so, a 10,000kg ship moving at 5km/sec without a warp field would only have a mass of 1kg if accelerated to 500km/sec in a warp field.  So getting hit by a warp ship would impart the same impact force as if it had no warp field.  Even if you do not impart this mechanic, it still takes a LOT of energy to destroy a planet.  Even if said ship did not lose mass, you still only have an impact of 1.25e15J which is equal to a 298 kiloton nuke.  Enough to devastate a small city, but nowhere near world smashing.  You could actually do more damage with a same mass nuke.

**Free energy or Perpetual motion machines (Yes & No):** No in that as long as maintaining the warp field costs as much energy over time as you would expend moving your ship with a reaction drive, there is no free energy.  Yes because you say you want "near light speeds in narratively convenient amounts of time ... and not be giant tanks of reaction mass".  By asking for this your setting is basically dictating that this is a free energy device, or you will need a fictional source of power that is more potent than Anti-matter. That said, a better than antimatter fuel source would by definition make FTL possible which you are trying to avoid.

Comment: `Planet-killing kinetic missiles (No)`?? [The annihilating effects of space travel](https://www.sydney.edu.au/news/84.html?newsstoryid=8812). In essence, trapped particles along the voyage; at deceleration stage, these particles are released, as hard gamma rays based on the energy they have.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi The annihilating effects of space travel requires travel over VERY long distances.  There is not enough matter in space for this to have planetary scale destructive abilities on an STL Alcubierre drive.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response!  Yes, I like the idea of the Alcubierre drive, and it's implied ship design.  I would not use the term "Alcubierre" in this proposed universe, to avoid confusion with FTL drives.

Comment: @TimMcClelland Thanks, I added a few more details just for better clarity.  That said, if this is for a novel or show, I would totally recommend adding a  scene where someone realizes that it is basically an Alcubierre drive as your science nerd audience will appreciate it. That way you have the opportunity to explain something like "Well, sort of... we would only call it an Alcubierre drive if it could violate all the real world limitations that keep it from going faster than light, but here in the real world, we're still stuck with McClelland drives."

Comment: "McClelland drives" I like the sound of that!

Comment: Or you could call it the Nosajimiki drive: named after the 21st century ummm... "physicist" who predicted the physical limitations of warp sheer.  But it's your story so call it what you like ;D

Comment: LOL.  I like that sound of that even better, actually.